# Composer (Facebook Ads SDK) setup with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, sdk, composer-php

I have a CodeIgniter application. I've been trying to set it up to work with Facebook ADS SDK ( https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk ).

I want to use a simple lines in my controller like:

```
use FacebookAds\Object\CustomAudience;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\CustomAudienceFields;
use FacebookAds\Object\Values\CustomAudienceSubtypes;

$audience = new CustomAudience(null, 'act_123123');
```

I have created composer.json file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "facebook/php-ads-sdk": "2.8.*"
    }
}
```

I let it through command

```
php composer.phar install --no-dev
```

And everything worked fine. It installed me autoload.php with external facebook folder.

Now when it comes to the part where I need to make it work with CodeIgniter I constantly get errors.

### I tried two different approaches:

First was to include it in my index.php Like this:

```
include_once 'application/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

However I was getting errors for not loading my classes that are in application/core folder (Back_Controller is extending CI_Controller and I am using Back_Controller in my every controller, I also have My_Model and Front_Controller there).

Second aproach:
To use CodeIgniter's feature to use Auto-loader together with Composer. So I changed in the config:

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;
```

Both approaches returned me the same errors:

> "Fatal error: Class 'Back_Controller' not found in /public_html/application/controllers/admin/Shops.php on line 4
>
> Warning: include(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(application/errors/html/error_php.php) is not within the allowed
>   path(s): () in /public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 269"

How can I set it up so Facebook SDK actually works together with CodeIgniter?
Any help will be very appreciated. Thank you.

I am thinking that one of the solutions would be to add "autoload" to composer.json so it loads my core classes but I can't figure out how should it be. I tried:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Back_Controller\\":"core/"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Include the main Api file

```
include APPPATH.'vendor/wherever_your_sdk_is/FacebookAds/Api.php';
```

Then do the following... as per documentation...

```
use FacebookAds\Api;

// Initialize a new Session and instanciate an Api object
Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token);

// The Api object is now available trough singleton
$api = Api::instance();
```

Comment: I included Api.php file and tried to init API on my controller's constructor. However, it just gave me another exception. Type: Error

Message: Class 'FacebookAds\Session' not found

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. 
I just added "autoload" to composer.json to autoload my core files and now both solutions that I tried before - works.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "":"core/"
    }
}
```